# Outbound Channel Adapter in SpringIntegration FTP

Tags: spring-integration

Do we have support for Outbound Channel Adapter in Spring Integration with annotation based? Please share link for example which supports.

Answer (score 0):

See [Programming Tips](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/overview.html#programming-tips) in the Reference Manual, where we have a sample for XMPP chat message sending:

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "input")
public MessageHandler sendChatMessageHandler(XMPPConnection xmppConnection) {
    ChatMessageSendingMessageHandler handler = new ChatMessageSendingMessageHandler(xmppConnection);

    DefaultXmppHeaderMapper xmppHeaderMapper = new DefaultXmppHeaderMapper();
    xmppHeaderMapper.setRequestHeaderNames("*");
    handler.setHeaderMapper(xmppHeaderMapper);

    return handler;
}
```

The same technique is applied for the `FtpMessageHandler`.

Also see [Annotation Support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations_on_beans) there as well.